# How to transmit video from android phone to phone

Tags: java, android, video, networking, transmission

I am a highschool student working on a quadcopter project. I am using an android phone instead of a traditional microcontroller because of the phone's speed and other features. The main point of using android phone is for video transmission. I have knowledge in a wide range of programming languages but not so much with networking.
How do I transmit video data from the camera of one phone to another over the network?

If you can direct me on what classes or functions I need to look up on specifically it would also be a great help.
Since I am not that proficient in networking terms and ways it would be helpful, if you would assume that I have minimal knowledge on data transferring over network but I have been using java for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some working example here:

http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/

An then, create a RSTP Client:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

> The following network protocols are supported for audio and video
>   playback:
>
> RTSP (RTP, SDP)

Comment: one more question - is it better to sample jpeg images or smaller chunks of videos..considering the application....

Comment: If you don't want to accept the first answer, I will be less likely to answer the second one ;-)

Comment: i am new here sry ab that .. i didnt know i had to do that
thanks for u responses